# how to refer to Google Sheets range with fixed ends and variable number of columns

Tags: google-sheets

Short version: I'm looking for a way to say this:

```
function(cell(row(),column($B3)+1) : cell(row(),column($F3)-1))
```

where the range I want is BETWEEN columns B and F.  That way, if I add more columns between B and F, even if they are left of B or right of F, they are still included in the range.  But Google Sheets doesn't seem to support such syntax.

Long version:  I have a Google Sheets doc with some columns of headers on the left, some columns of more info on the right, and a voting area in the middle.  The number of columns in the middle varies from time to time as we add or remove voters.  Voters mark their choices with a non-blank in a cell.  Just to the right of the voting area is a Sum column where we record the number of non-blank cells in the voting area in that row.

So, for example, we might have:

```
            C      D      E     F
colA colB voter1 voter2 voter3 Sum header header
info info   X             X     2   info   info
info info   X      X            2   info   info
```

The formula in the Sum cell on row 3 is

```
=columns(B3:F3)-2-countblank(C3:E3)
```

The problem is to fix the Sum formula so that it will always work as we add or remove voters.  Voters may be added to the left of the first voter, to the right of the last, or anywhere in between, and any voter might be removed.  Any of the info cells might be blank.  The B and F references work as I want as voters are added or removed, always referring to the columns just before and just after the voting area.  But the countblank result goes wrong when a voter is added before the first voter or after the last; countblank does not include the new voter's column in the formula's range.

All suggestions appreciated, although I would like to do this with a formula rather than a script.

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIF function ex: COUNTIF(C3:E3, "x")

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it has the same problem as the original: when I insert a new voter before the first or after the last, the range is not adjusted to include them.